Geometric nodes scatter with camera culling [inc. distance and field] but hiding behind the objects
Is it possible for a scatter made with geometric nodes not to create instances behind objects? The geometric node is on the plane, but I want it not to create instances where they are simply unnecessary, i.e. behind every object that covers the space.
